# If $x = a( \theta +\sin \theta)$ and $y = a(1-\cos \theta)$ then find $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $x = a( \theta +\sin \theta)$ and $y = a(1-\cos \theta)$ then $\frac{dy}{dx}$ will be equal to :

$a) \sin \frac{\theta}{2}$

$b) \cos \frac{\theta}{2}$

$c) \tan \frac{\theta}{2}$

$d) \cot \frac{\theta}{2}$

I have solved till : $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\sin \theta}{1 + \cos \theta}$ using $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{d \theta} . \frac{d \theta}{dx}$.

How do I reduce to the option's forms?

Comment: I recognize a tangent half angle formula in your solution

Comment: Or double angle formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint $$\sin(x)=2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)$$ and $$1+\cos(x)=2\cos^2(x/2)$$

Comment: Ohh, that was easy. Thanks !!

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{\sin a}{1+\cos a}=\frac{\sin\frac{a}{2}cos\frac{a}{2}}{{\cos^2\frac{a}{2}}} $$

$=\tan\frac{a}{2} $ is the solution

( Rotation of cycloid?)